# Set up conda rna seq analysis

Tags: conda, zsh

I'm trying to set up Conda on MacOS for RNA sequencing analysis. However, I keep getting the error message

```bash
(conda not installed): 

    active environment : base 
   active env location : /Users/mesalie/miniconda 
           shell level : 1 
      user config file : /Users/mesalie/.condarc 
populated config files : /Users/mesalie/.condarc 
         conda version : 4.12.0 
   conda-build version : not installed 
        python version : 3.9.12.final.0 
      virtual packages : __osx=10.13.6=0 __unix=0=0 __archspec=1=x86_64 
      base environment : /Users/mesalie/miniconda (writable) 
     conda av data dir : /Users/mesalie/miniconda/etc/conda 
 conda av metadata url : None 
          channel URLs : https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge/osx-64 
                         https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge/noarch 
                         https://conda.anaconda.org/bioconda/osx-64 
                         https://conda.anaconda.org/bioconda/noarch 
                         https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/osx-64 
                         https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/noarch 
                         https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/osx-64 
                         https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/noarch 
         package cache : /Users/mesalie/miniconda/pkgs /Users/mesalie/.conda/pkgs 
      envs directories : /Users/mesalie/miniconda/envs /Users/mesalie/.conda/envs 
              platform : osx-64
```

I used the following commands:

```bash
bash ~/Miniconda3-latest-MacOSX-x86_64.sh -b -p $HOME/miniconda 
source $HOME/miniconda/bin/activate 

conda init zsh 
conda info  (shows not installed)
```

Could someone please advise me on how to correct this error message.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Use full path to `conda` when first running initialization, e.g., `~/miniconda/condabin/conda init zsh`. Then restart the shell.